# Loop in netlogo to create multiple attributes

Tags: loops, foreach, netlogo

I need help for the following issue:
I need to create a list of 20 income as income = y - c where
y and c are inputs and y is a variable: I have y0 y1 y2, so I want income0, income1, income2.
Can you suggest to me where I can study how to do that? I searched netlogo loop and netlogo foreach on google, but I cannot find anything.
 Thanks

Comment: Are these global variables or are they turtle attributes? Are you sure you want 40 different variables? If I see variable names like income0 income1 income2 etc, I always think about whether what i really want is a single variable income that is a list. So instead of income0 = 5, income1 = 10, income2 = 12..., I would have a variable income = [5, 10, 12 .....]

Comment: Basically I am doing a maximization by attemps: y is the amount of turnover I want to declare (20 attempts). Then I have 20 incomes and 20 utility functions. Then I create a list of utilities choosing the maximum. Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: 20 utility functions, or 20 utility values from the same function with different inputs? I think you need to provide some example data - what you are feeding in and what you want out - to have any chance of a sensible answer.

Comment: Hi Jen, I need 20 utility values (eu) from the same function with different inputs to have a list. The only input to change is income (income0, income2...) From this list I will choose the maximimum using set eumax max ( list eu0 ... eu20)

Comment: as Jen indicates, you need to revise your question to be more specific and explicit about what you're trying to do, or you're unlikely to get any usable help.